# How to I pass a Stripe Firebase Cloud Function Error To The Client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When I create a cloud function to process a charge on a user’s card (by writing a stripe token to firebase and using a cloud function to charge), how do I pass errors (like a declined card due to insufficient funds) to the client. If it’s important, I’m using the firebase web sdk to send the tokens.

Answer (score 0):

write the errors to a firebase database so that you can read the errors from the database and show them where you need to.

Comment: There's always a delay when the writing an error to the firebase database. When I check for an error, I wasn't written on time. I have to delay the code from running using setInterval(), which worked on my testing on my local machine but failed when testing on a phone.

Comment: If you're using teh real-time database, it is unlikely to be the database write that is slowing things down.,If you're using firestore you can switch to the realtime database just for the error writes. The cloud function itself is what usually takes a while to process. Perhaps you could log a few timestamps to see whats causing the delay. When I get a similar issue I also write a boolean along with the error data so that I can launch whatever successive against when the boolean is true, rather than having to set timeouts.

Comment: If my response answered your question please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use a Firebase HTTP cloud function and just send the token to the link firebase sets for the function. Like so,

```
exports.addSourceToCustomer = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
const token = req.body.token // use the stripe token however you like here
// when an error occurs use res.status(errorCode).send(errorMessage);
// which sends the error back to the client that made the request
});
```